# How to compare nulls without using IsNull in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I write the below statement without using `IsNULL`?

```
 Case 
    When (IsNull(Email_Ind, '') != 'N' 
       then 'e' 
       else 'n' 
 end
```

Does this get the right results ?

```
Case 
   When Email_Ind != 'N' and Email_Ind is not null  
      then 'e' 
      else 'n' 
end
```

Comment: Why don't you like ISNULL? That may hurt SQL Server's feelings :)

Comment: Haha.. I am using always encryption on few columns and it does not like IsNull

Comment: actually i think it's fine, just hard to read. My answer isn't any different from yours, just different.

Comment: @scsimon *my answer isn't any different from yours, just different*?, so, is it different or not?

Comment: My apologies, the results shouldn't be different, thus your case should be fine IMHO.

Comment: The simpler would be `CASE WHEN Email_Ind = 'N' THEN 'n' ELSE 'e' END`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I think the only reason he can't simply reduce to a comparison on the value `N` is because `null` is also supposed to be treated as `N` and this reduction would treat null as `E`. I'm assuming he doesn't invert the logic on `E` because there are also multiple strings for `E`.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 NULL is treated differently in the 1st code sample and in the 2nd. My expression is equivalent to the 1st one.

Comment: Why are you asking a question that you can easily answer yourself with a simple test?

Comment: What happens when you run each statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case statement looks fine. It's just a matter of preference on how to write it. To me, this is more easily understandable but that's not the case for all i'm sure.

```
Case When Email_Ind != 'N' or Email_Ind is null  then 'e' else 'n' end
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [EXCEPT and INTERSECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) for this sort of thing:

```
select case when (select Email_Ind intersect select 'Y') = 1 then 'E' else 'N' end
```

As suggested by @ypercubeᵀᴹ, this would also work (and is probably the more semantic way to state the query):

```
select case when exists (select Email_Ind intersect select 'Y') then 'E' else 'N' end
```

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Sorry, I forgot an `= 1`.

Comment: Clever, but anyone who comes across this code will have to ponder it a bit before they realize it's purpose is just a != 'N' OR is null.  It's like leaving a little rubiks cube in your code that developers have to solve just to understand the purpose.

Comment: @AaronLS How in the world is the idiomatic T-SQL method for gracefully comparing `nulls` clever or a Rubik's cube? I'd argue that someone who doesn't understand T-SQL could still digest this version easier than they could pull apart an `IsNull(<value>, '') != ''` comparison due to the fact that it very nearly states IN ENGLISH what it actually does.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 `intersect` is a set operation directly derived from set theory.  Its primary purpose is not intended as a graceful way of comparing `nulls`.  You have leveraged its behavior to achieve such a comparison, and therefore I consider it "clever".  It's not a matter of understanding SQL, it's a matter of conveying the **purpose** of the code.  You should absolutely lean towards readability so long as you have not made a significant sacrifice in performance.

Comment: @AaronLS Yeah, and I still maintain that it's easier to understand `select 'Value' intersect select 'Value'` than `NullIf('Value', '') = 'Value'`. Even better, you don't need to understand code to understand the former because you can infer the meaning. It is a set based operation and we are using a set based language after all...

Comment: @Kittoes0124 But you aren't comparing sets.  You're comparing single values, and that's what Boolean logic is for.  Yes it's a set based language for querying sets, but you've used it for comparing single values.  That's what comparison operators are for.  By misusing these operators, then you convey to the reader you are comparing sets, when your sets are really a set of single values.  Such a set is technically valid, but it completely conveys the wrong thing.  Use the right tool for the job.  Comparison operators for comparing.

Comment: @AaronLS A set of one is still a set. A set of nothing is still a set. There is no "misuse" here sir...

Comment: @Kittoes0124 Read please, I already said "Such a set is technically valid, but it completely conveys the wrong thing." You are using a hammer to drive a screw. You can do it, but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: If you write code like this I guarantee you that you will piss off the majority of developers that have to come behind and see 1) Oh we have a set comparison operator 2) The left side is Email, the right side is selecting a single item 3) Ok the result is just going to be the set { 'Y' } 4) we've now compared the set { 'Y' } to 1. 5) So that will evaluate to true if the set is non-empty? 6) So all this just to accomplish what they could have done with a comparison operator?

Comment: @AaronLS If someone gets pissed over the use of a set based operator in a set based language then they don't deserve to call themselves a developer. `IsNull` isn't even a part of the ANSI SQL standard while `exists`, `intersect`, and `except` are. Knock the performance of the set based version all you want (it IS less efficient when your code lacks branches) but claiming that it is somehow misusing SQL is disingenuous at best.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 As I've said again and again, it's not about SQL being a set based language, it is about the operation being performed being a comparison operation, not a set based operation.  You solve set based problems with set based operators.  You solve value comparison problems with comparison operators. "don't deserve to call themselves a developer" You have demonstrated that you are in no position to dictate who should and should not be a developer.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 "Knock the performance of the set based version " Not once did I knock the performance of the set based operation. For about the 3rd time you've failed to read my response. I outlined the mental steps one has to jump through before they discover the intention of your code was never to solve a set based problem, but instead to perform a very simple comparison that you made unnecessarily obtuse by using a set based operation between two singular values. That has nothing to do with performance, and everything to do with your code being self documenting and conveying **intent**.

Comment: You should be aware that `Email_Ind != 'N' or Email_Ind is null` is ANSI compliant.  So if that's your reasoning or choosing such an obtuse approach, it doesn't hold its ground.

Comment: @Aaron the ONLY thing I'm arguing this entire time is that there is absolutely nothing clever going on here and that the idea of this style *is* to capture intent. It very nearly describes the solution in plain English while still being code.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 In plain English the solution requested was "If Email_Ind is 'N' or not specified then 'e', else 'n" or conversely 'If Email_Ind is specified and 'Y', then 'n' else 'e'".  Your solution conveys "If a set exists which is the intersection of the set { Email_ind } and the set { 'Y' } then 'e' else 'n'"  You forced a simple single value comparison into a set based operation. You added an unnecessary abstraction. Yes a single item can be interpreted as a set.  You can also cast integers to strings.  Doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @AaronLS Only if you insist on being utterly pedantic, and you clearly do, so have a good night.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 "A set of one is still a set. A set of nothing is still a set." Who is being pedantic again?

Comment: @AaronLS Ugh, you originally brought up those as technicalities chief. Which is like saying that zero and one are technically integers. There's nothing technical about either situation just like there's nothing clever going on here: just basic ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 I stated this only as an anticipation of your weak argument as you were already being pretty pedantic. I anticipated the pedantic defense stating: "Such a set is technically valid, but it completely conveys the wrong thing. Use the right tool for the job. Comparison operators for comparing."  All you did was make the very pedantic argument I anticipated you would make.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 You could add 50 layers of ANSI SQL here that any SQL developer would understand what is happening at each step.  But it would take them hours to get to the end result of understanding that all you were trying to accomplish was a simple value comparison and eventually come to the conclusion that you have no concept of when to use value comparisons.

Comment: I outlined the steps a competent developer would go through to interpret the purpose of your code.   The issue is not that you are using any features of SQL that are difficult to understand.  They are straightforward features.  What is in the use of those features you've described comparison of two sets, when neither side of the set operator is a set, except by the most pedantic interpretation. Yes it works in the sense that a Rube Goldberg machine "works".